# Qual a diferença entre align-items e align-content?

Tags: css, flexbox

Existe alguma diferença entre o `align-items` e o `align-content`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `align-items`

A propriedade `align-items` alinha os itens dentro de um container flex ao longo do eixo cruzado (perpendicular). Funciona da mesma forma que o `justify-content` para o eixo principal.

No caso do valor padrão de `flex-direction: row`, o eixo cruzado corresponde à vertical e o eixo principal corresponde à horizontal. Com `flex-direction: column`, esses dois são trocados respectivamente. Ou seja, na direção `row`, um `align-items: center` alinharia os elementos com a altura no centro da linha:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #0066ff;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.box1 { height: 50px; }
.box2 { height: 30px; }
.box3 { height: 80px; }
.box4 { height: 60px; }
.box5 { height: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box box1">1</div>
  <div class="box box2">2</div>
  <div class="box box3">3</div>
  <div class="box box4">4</div>
  <div class="box box5">5</div>
</div>
```

## `align-content`

A propriedade `align-content` alinha as linhas de um container flex quando há espaço extra no eixo cruzado. Ou seja, não tem efeito algum dentro dos itens de uma única linha.

```js
function alignItems() {
  document.querySelector('.container').classList.toggle("alignItems");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
  align-content: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.alignItems { align-items: flex-end; }

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #0066ff;
  margin: 0 4px;
}

.box1 { height: 50px; }
.box2 { height: 30px; }
.box3 { height: 80px; }
.box4 { height: 60px; }
.box5 { height: 20px; }
```

```html
<button onClick={alignItems()}>Toggle align-items: flex-end</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">1</div>
    <div class="box box2">2</div>
    <div class="box box3">3</div>
    <div class="box box4">4</div>
    <div class="box box5">5</div>
    <div class="box box1">6</div>
    <div class="box box2">7</div>
    <div class="box box3">8</div>
    <div class="box box4">9</div>
    <div class="box box5">10</div>
</div>
```

Referências:

- [What's the difference between align-content and align-items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944673/8839059)
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)